# Timezone option is not working in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I use Google Chrome browser. When I click the Timezone filter option, it does nothing. It doesn't list various time zones as it used to be.

Can someone help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved on its own after clearing the cookies.

Comment: Please mark yourself for others' reference,thanks for your sharing.